# How can I have my boxes horizontally aligned?

Tags: python, css

This is ultimately just one box. But since it has the 'for' loop, it should have 3 boxes horizontally aligned.

```html
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        {% for hobby in hobbies.all %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ hobby.image.url }}"/>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">{{ hobby.summary }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I keep having this:
[image: Click to see the result of the code]

What will I do?

Comment: You are making a new row in every iteration. Your `<div class="row">` resides with in `for` loop.

Comment: your loop make single `"row"` for every hobbies it's not right way, `"col-md-4"` must be run in loop for horizontal view..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      {% for hobby in hobbies.all %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ hobby.image.url }}" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">{{ hobby.summary }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

You `class="row"` should be outside the loop.

`class="row"` creates row in a table format that means each item within a loop will create a row and then a column inside i.e. you see your each cards in new row.

For getting the cards horizontally, all the cards should be place within a single row.

Comment: Hey Shiladitya. Thank you soooo much. It worked! Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome @ZeddrixFabian